# Gearman workers cannot access the PHP framework

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, gearman

Hi I've installed and configured Gearman. So far it has been great trying out examples, and when I came to the part where I am actually going to use it in my project, that's where my problem began.

I'm using Yii php framework in my project, and I included all my worker files in the main project directory.

```
ProjectName/workers/worker.php
```

My workers' function are to insert values in the database given a parameter. So I had to include sql query, and since i'm using Yii, I use the :

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

and I encounter the error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Yii' not found in /home/user/lappstack-5.4.34-0/apache2/htdocs/ProjectName/workers/worker.php on line 52
```

It seems that my CLI PHP cannot find Yii, so I tried doing it old school using PDO :

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:db...........'usr','pas');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

and I get the error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /home/user/lappstack-5.4.34-0/apache2/htdocs/ProjectName/workers/worker.php:54
```

So it seems that the worker basically doesn't have a server environment unlike my web application that can access Yii functions and what not. How do resolve this?

Comment: if your going to use yii, you have to use it properly, are you using command line or web interface?

Comment: yes i'm using command line, rather than in a web controller/action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you spawn your workers? In order to use Yii your workers need to be instantiated with such command:
/home/sites/projectName/php yiic command-name

Please read the documentation on creating commands it is well written:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console

Comment: how do I do this exactly? i tried using these : 

"/home/sites/projectName/php yiic worker.php:

and

"/home/sites/projectName/yiic worker.php"

and 

"/home/sites/projectName yiic shell php worker.php"

and it just puts up the help details on the command line

Comment: anyway this was a big help :) i didn't know i had to use yiic rather than direct 'php' command. I had a start to look into, and I resolved it by createing a yii console application using CConsoleCommand that uses the yiic. So that my console app runs in the yii environment :)